# ignore socket.error in python

Tags: python, sockets

using a simple code to get hostname from ip address.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import os
import sys

try:
        fdes = open ("ip.txt","r")
        for line in fdes.readlines():
                print socket.gethostbyaddr(line)
except Exception:
        pass
```

e.g ip.txt have ip address:

> 10.10.1.10,
>   10.10.1.20,
>   10.10.1.30,
>   10.10.1.40,
>   10.10.1.50,
>   10.10.1.60,
>   10.10.1.70,

there is no hostname for 10.10.1.40, so the code breaks here, do not continue further, Error is **"socket.herror:[errno 1] Unknown Host"**

how i can forcefully ignore the error if a hostname is not available for as ip address ?

Comment: usually try/except surrounds one critical statement, if it fails all of its block are skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This moves the hostname related code into the try/except block, while keeping the file reading stuff out of it; so if an exception is thrown your file reading code will still continue.

```
fdes = open("ip.txt","r")

for line in fdes.readlines():
    try:
        print socket.gethostbyaddr(line)
    except socket.error:
        pass
```

Note: this code only ignores `socket.error` exceptions while leaving all other exceptions unhandled (so a Ctrl+C which throws a KeyboardInterrupt will still stop the program).

Comment: @Nabla true, but I try to keep my code as similar as possible to the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Exception` in your code with `socket.error`:

```
try:
    # Do something with sockets that might throw an error
except socket.error:
    pass # Basically, ignore the error
```

This will ensure that you don't unintentionally ignore other errors in your code.

If you want to do something with the error, perhaps log it, use this code:

```
try:
    # Operation that might throw a socket error
except socket.error as e:
    print e
    # Do something with the error object
```

Comment: thanks, pardon my layman ship with scripting, what should i put here to replace **# ONLY catch socket errors**